# Tecla de atalho para "surround with" no Notepad++

Tags: teclado, notepad++

O editor PhpStorm tem uma tecla de atalho para o comando "surround with", alguém sabe se o Notepad++ tem este recurso e qual a tecla de atalho?

Comment: Essa pergunta merece os votos de fechamento? Abri um questionamento no meta sobre o assunto: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6933/64969

Comment: Me parece que o Notepad++ não tem essa capacidade, mas me parece tb (eu não uso o app) que o mesmo possui funções de gravar macros onde vc pode adicionar funcionalidades. Veja esta resposta no SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4181826/1377664

Answer (score 7):

O Notepad++ não possui essa capacidade nativamente. Você tem duas opções para adicionar aspas, parênteses etc. ao redor de uma seleção.

- Gravar macros -> existem vários locais na internet que ensinam a fazer isso. Alguns sugerem gambiarras que vão sujar a área de transferência, então cuidado. No final, fica a seu critério criar uma macro que seja eficiente e precisa.
- Usar plugins, como o [SurroundSelection](https://github.com/dail8859/SurroundSelection). Caso alguém conheça mais plugins, sintam-se a vontade para editar a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno amigos. Na verdade, deixei de usar o Notepad++ como editor principal, passei a usar o Atom. Por mim podemos encerrar esse assunto.